GIT Subtree Merge of Two Projects Sharing Folder Name
I'm trying to convert our vendor drop approach from SVN to GIT. The problem I'm trying to solve is that there are two vendor drops that to some extend use the same folder structure and need to be merged into a project. Example:
VendorDropA/
├─ library/
│  ├─ common/
│  │  ├─ libACommon.c
│  ├─ libA/
│  │  ├─ libA.c

VendorDropB/
├─ library/
│  ├─ common/
│  │  ├─ libBCommon.c
│  ├─ libB/
│  │  ├─ libB.c


The project should look like
Project/
├─ library/
│  ├─ common/
│  │  ├─ libACommon.c
│  │  ├─ libBCommon.c
│  ├─ libA/
│  │  ├─ libA.c
│  ├─ libB/
│  │  ├─ libB.c
├─ projectFiles/
│  ├─ projectFile.c

The challenge is that both - VendorDropA and VendorDropB - are evolving over time and I need to be able to merge changes to the project and keep the history. With SVN this was possible using SVN copy/merge on individual files in the library folder.
I did not made the best experience in the past using submodules therefore I tried replicating this using subtree using the following
git clone https://git/project/VendorDropTest.git
cd VendorDropTest

# Prepare subtree for VendorDropA
git remote add -f VendorDropA https://git/project/VendorDropA.git
git checkout VendorDropA/main
git subtree split --prefix library/common -b VendorACommon
git subtree split --prefix library/libA -b VendorALib

# Prepare subtree for VendorDropB
git remote add -f VendorDropB https://git/project/VendorDropB.git
git checkout VendorDropB/main
git subtree split --prefix library/common -b VendorBCommon
git subtree split --prefix library/libB -b VendorBLib

# Create the project
git checkout main
git subtree add --prefix library/common VendorACommon --squash
git subtree merge --prefix library/common VendorBCommon --squash

The problem is that the moment I run the last comment the files from VendorDropA are removed and only those from VendorDropB are available.

I tried to use different merge strategy like "-s ours" but they don't seem to be available for subtree merge
I also tried to --no-commit or similar the then later unstage the files from VendorDropA but also this seems not available for subtree merge
I then tried read-tree like below

git subtree add --prefix library/common VendorACommon --squash
git read-tree --prefix library/common -u VendorBCommon 

which at least makes the files stay but this way I loose the history of the files from VendorB and therefore can't merge any updates later.
